# Change the default styling of underlined hotkey text in buttons

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, button

In my windows form, I have a button with a shortcut code using &. It looks like below:

[image]

It **Text** property has the value **&Sales Bill - Cash**

See that its default styling for the highlighted shortcut code is an `underline`. Instead, I would like to change that styling to `Underline` + `Bold` + `Different color`

Is that possible somehow?

Comment: The clue for changing the cues: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.changeuicues(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do is possible. I've never seen anything that allowed you to style just the Hotkey text. You could probably tackle the problem a different way by using an image that had the text on it for your button but then you'd lose some functionality that you get by default (the text wouldn't style with the users Windows style setting, the Underline would always be visible, etc.)

Answer (score 2):

To change the font style on just a portion of the text you will have to draw the button yourself. With some controls you can use "owner draw" mechanisms, sometimes you can just derive from the class and override OnPaint, or at worst case you can create a UserControl that implements button-like behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Font Property & Fore Color Property of the Button

```
this.button1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 12F, ((System.Drawing.FontStyle)(((System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold | System.Drawing.FontStyle.Italic)
                            | System.Drawing.FontStyle.Underline))), System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
this.button1.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Maroon;
```